# How can I hook the preprocessor in Clang, XCode, and MSVS? (GCC works)

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, clang, preprocessor

I'm using an external preprocessor (pyexpander) for my cross-platform/cross-IDE c++ project*. GCC already works nicely with the `-no-integrated-cpp -B${PWD}` option. I could manually preprocess each file into a specific temp dir, then compile the processed files. But is there a better way? Specifically, I'd love to hook the native preprocessors so IDE-level code analysis is happy (code completion and error checking). Any hints how I can achieve this would be much appreciated.

*"But why not use c++ macros?" They can't do macro-macros and I need that.

*"But why not use m4?" Because python happens to already be a requirement for this codebase, and m4 seems to not come with MSVS and thus would be yet another requirement/point of failure. I would still have to resolve the original preprocessor problem.

*"But why not use language something_better?" Because I have no choice in the matter. (Though I would love to use nim all the way!!)

Comment: Looked at `libclang`?

Comment: I'm currently looking into overriding the default compiler executables with a small executable(script?) which produces the macro processed code and passes it to the the real compiler executable. cl.exe for MSVS, clang for XCode. What a mess. Too bad compilers don't have a "use custom defined preprocessor first" switch!

Comment: And why do you need that?

Comment: Because I need macro-macros.

Comment: libclang could work, and that is a nice option to know about. Thanks @arrowd. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @arrowd OP already answered: "requirement for custom preprocessor."  Asking why someone needs that is like asking why anyone would need more than 640KB of RAM.  The real question is: "why would anyone _not_ want a superior preprocessor?"

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug Being curious became a sin?